# Deeplearning course: Error in loading datasets

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to have a copy of python assignments of the Deepleaning specilization by Andrew NG and to run them on my local machine. I have downloaded the assignments from this repository- https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-deep-learning-specialization.

For [this jupyter notebook assignment](https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-deep-learning-specialization/blob/master/C4%20-%20Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Week%201/Convolution_model_Application_v1a.ipynb) (`>C4-Convolutional Neural Networks> Week 1> Convolution_model_Application_v1a.ipynb`), the first cell works fine on my computer but the second cell

```
# Loading the data (signs)
X_train_orig, Y_train_orig, X_test_orig, Y_test_orig, classes = load_dataset()
```

gives the following error-

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6204c374be26> in <module>
      1 # Loading the data (signs)
----> 2 X_train_orig, Y_train_orig, X_test_orig, Y_test_orig, classes = load_dataset()

~/Documents/Coursera Deep Learning/C4 - Convolutional Neural Networks/Week 1/cnn_utils.py in load_dataset()
      7 
      8 def load_dataset():
----> 9     train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/train_signs.h5', "r")
     10     train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:]) # your train set features
     11     train_set_y_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:]) # your train set labels

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
    404             with phil:
    405                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, **kwds)
--> 406                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
    407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
    408                                swmr=swmr)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    171         if swmr and swmr_support:
    172             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 173         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    174     elif mode == 'r+':
    175         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The dataset is corrupted, you can find a new one here
https://github.com/ooleksyuk/Convolutional-Neural-Networks/tree/master/week1/assignments/datasets

Answer (score 0):

Try click the green button 'Code' in https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-deep-learning-specialization and download everything in one go. Then reload the Jupyter Notebook.

I think you did not download the directory 'datasets'

Comment: I have downloaded the complete repository, I have the folder 'datasets'.

Comment: did you run setup.sh to (i) download a pre-trained VGG-19 dataset and (ii) extract the zip'd pre-trained models and datasets that are needed for all the assignments?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I run setup.sh, but I received this error for multiple zip files `End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ./ResNet50.h5.zip or
        ./ResNet50.h5.zip.zip, and cannot find ./ResNet50.h5.zip.ZIP, period.`